# Is it possible to use two json_encode() in one php file?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to use json to send text and blob image information from MySQL to iPhone App.
However, someone told me that I should separate text and blob image info because blob is technically not binary - thus I have to use base64_encode(). Well.... I'm going to create two php files but want to check if it's possible to do it in one php file.  :/   I tried but n o luck yet... Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode), the function, as often as you want.
But throwing the output together is not going to work.

If you intended to do

```
print json_encode($data_array); 
print json_encode($image_blob);
```

Then this will lead to an **invalid JSON** response.
Like `{"data":123} {"image":"PNG%...."}`

You need to combine the data and the image blob somehow if you want this to work in one response:

```
print json_encode(array_merge($data_ar, array("image"=>$image_blob)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to have some kind of conditional to decide which JSON document you are going to return… but if you are going to serve the image up separately then you are almost certainly better off just serving up the image and not encoding it in a JSON document.

Comment: Ummm that means I can receive both of them using objc & json from one php page?

Comment: No, it doesn't. One script can branch and do two different things depending on the data it is sent.

Comment: Now I see what you mean :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such restriction. You can use json_encode as many times as you need.

Comment: Ummm that means I can receive both of them using objc & json from one php page?

Comment: Technically true. But you cannot output more than ONE json string at a time. As mario shows in his answer - two separate json strings is a syntax error.